# Django Queryset datetime filtering

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views

I have a set of study sessions that have date and time details and I was wondering how I could go about filtering to just show users upcoming study sessions that are occurring either today or after today in my html file? Here is the model for the session.

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.today()
Appointment.objects.filter(date__gte=now)
```

Comment: Will this allow me to also show upcoming sessions?

Comment: This is for showing upcoming Appointment objects. Thus the date_gte=now. 
gte means greater than or equal to.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the timestamp of the database with a [**`Now`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#now):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Appointment.objects.filter(date__gte=Now())
```

Comment: Will this allow me to also show upcoming sessions?